# Salesforce: domain object doesn't contain all expected hosts

Tags: salesforce, apex

In Apex I have this url for the profile photo: /profilephoto/7288L000000eFHI/F

I could query the domain object to get the host, but the domain object only contains:

```
hkk4-dev-ed.my.salesforce-sites.com
hkk4-dev-ed.my.site.com
```

They don't work for the profile photo. However the host that works is:

```
 hkk4-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
```

Why isn't that one in the domain object? Is there something I need to do to add that domain to the domain object so that I can query with soql?

I'm trying to have something like that at the end:

https://hkk4-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/profilephoto/7288L000000eFHI/F